# Background Image Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple website that only consists of background images inside a carousel that will move from left to right, with directional arrows. I have found one resources that provides a simple example however when I tried to reproduce their model, the script doesn't seem to define itself. Also, there is the second issue with actually making it full-screen since the demo is only 700x500.

Here is a link to the resource: [Dynamic Drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/bgcarousel.htm).

Also, here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>Hit Heavy</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />

<style type="text/css">
    div.bgcarousel { /* CSS for main carousel container */
        background: black center center no-repeat; 
        width: 100%;
    }

    img.navbutton { /* CSS for the nav buttons */
        margin: 5px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    div.slide{ /* CSS for each image's DIV container within main container */
        background-color: black;
        background-position: center center; /* center image within carousel */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover; /* CSS3 property to scale image within container? "cover" or     "contain" */
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bgcarousel.js" script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var firstbgcarousel=new bgCarousel({
    wrapperid: 'mybgcarousel', //ID of blank DIV on page to house carousel
    imagearray: [
        ['bg.jpg'], //["image_path", "optional description"]
        ['bg.jpg'],
        ['bg.jpg'],
        ['bg.jpg'] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'manual', pause:3000, cycles:2, stoponclick:false,  pauseonmouseover:true},
    navbuttons: ['left.png', 'right.png'], // path to nav images
    activeslideclass: 'selectedslide', // CSS class that gets added to currently shown DIV slide
    orientation: 'h', //Valid values: "h" or "v"
    persist: true, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    slideduration: 500 //transition duration (milliseconds)
})

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="mybgcarousel" class="bgcarousel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As for the javascript that backs the scripting within the html, you can view it [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/bgcarousel.js)

Comment: what do you mean by define itself ???

Comment: Let's say I inspect my website with the Chrome inspector. This is what the console tells me:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier bgcarousel.js:162
Uncaught ReferenceError: bgCarousel is not defined index.html:34

Comment: Plz check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line you have set the width to 100%

```
   div.bgcarousel{ /* CSS for main carousel container */
   background: black ; 
    width:700px; /* default dimensions of carousel */
    height:500px;
    }
```

Comment: It's not quite fixed yet. What ended up happening is that I changed the c to capitol from the html and css ends but background is still black.

Comment: I'm aware of that change, and I changed it back to 700x500 but it still doesn't fix it. When I look in the inspector, it seems as though the html doesn't even recognize the bgcarousel.js file period.

Answer (score 0):

@user2122160 Height is Important change the css like this

```
div.bgcarousel { /* CSS for main carousel container */
        background: black center center no-repeat; 
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

i created Slider based Your Code its Working Well without Error Link below:

> http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g7d74fb2c3b904c6a99923428881a8f81443981afd

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a $(document).ready() handler around that code, I think it's running BEFORE jquery and bgcarousel gets loaded, change the script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var firstbgcarousel=new bgCarousel({
    wrapperid: 'mybgcarousel', //ID of blank DIV on page to house carousel
    imagearray: [
        ['bg.jpg'], //["image_path", "optional description"]
        ['bg.jpg'],
        ['bg.jpg'],
        ['bg.jpg'] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'manual', pause:3000, cycles:2, stoponclick:false,  pauseonmouseover:true},
    navbuttons: ['left.png', 'right.png'], // path to nav images
    activeslideclass: 'selectedslide', // CSS class that gets added to currently shown DIV slide
    orientation: 'h', //Valid values: "h" or "v"
    persist: true, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    slideduration: 500 //transition duration (milliseconds)
  })
})
</script>
```

the $(document).ready part makes your code wait for the document to be loaded before executing your script